# Is the kernel of an action of a Hopf algebra on an algebra a biideal?

Tags: reference-request, ideals, hopf-algebras

[S.Dascalescu, C.Nastasescu and S.Raianu](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824704819) define the action of a Hopf algebra $H$ on an (associative) algebra $A$ as a map $H\times A\owns (h,a)\mapsto h\cdot a\in A$ which

- is an action of $H$ on $A$ as an algebra on a vector space and
- satisfies two supplementary conditions:
  $$
  h\cdot(a\cdot b)=\sum(h_1\cdot a)\cdot (h_2\cdot b),\qquad 
  h\cdot 1_A=\varepsilon(h)\cdot 1_A.
  $$

I think that the kernel of such an action, i.e. the set
$$
I=\{h\in H:\quad \forall a\in A\quad h\cdot a=0\},
$$
must be a [biideal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biideal) in $H$ as in a bialgebra, i.e.
$$
\Delta(I)\subseteq I\otimes H+H\otimes I,
$$
but this is quite far from me, I have no idea how people prove this. Can anybody enlighten me? Thank you.

P.S. I asked this also at [MathOverFlow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387255/is-the-kernel-of-an-action-of-a-hopf-algebra-on-an-algebra-a-biideal).

Comment: Well, it certainly is a left ideal.

Comment: @Berci, left ideal in which sense?

Comment: I mean, $h\cdot a=0\implies xh\cdot a=0$. And, because of the universal quantifier it is also right ideal: if for all $a$ we have $h\cdot a=0$ then in particular it holds with $x\cdot a$, so that $hx\cdot a=0$.

Comment: @Berci, of course, $I$ is a two-sided ideal in $H$ as in an algebra. The question is how to prove this embedding, $\Delta(I)\subseteq I\otimes H+H\otimes I$ (and whether it is indeed true).

Comment: I added a community wiki post, so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding [question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387255/is-the-kernel-of-an-action-of-a-hopf-algebra-on-an-algebra-a-biideal) has been answered by darij grinberg in the negative: $I$ is not necessarily a biideal.